# In R dplyr, gsub() in mutate() using column as the pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

```
zed = data.frame(name = c('Tom', 'Joe', 'Nick', 'Bill'), names = c('TomRyanTim', 'RobJoeMike', 'SteveKevinNick', 'EvanPacJimmy'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> zed
  name          names
1  Tom     TomRyanTim
2  Joe     RobJoeMike
3 Nick SteveKevinNick
4 Bill   EvanPacJimmy

> zed %>% dplyr::mutate(names = gsub(name, '', names))
  name          names
1  Tom        RyanTim
2  Joe     RobJoeMike
3 Nick SteveKevinNick
4 Bill   EvanPacJimmy

Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `names`.
ℹ `names = gsub(name, "", names)`.
ℹ argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

In the example above, the `mutate(gsub())` seems to be attempting to gsub the name `Tom` in every row, whereas I'd like for each row to gsub() the value in the `name` column. We are looking for the following output:

```
output$names = c('RyanTim', 'RobMike', SteveKevin', 'EvanPacJimmy')
```

Is it possible to update our code for the mutate + gsub to operate as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rowwise`:

```r
zed %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(names = gsub(name, '', names)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

To avoid using `rowwise`, you can use `stringr::str_replace_all` or `stringr::str_remove_all`:

```r
library(stringr)
zed %>%
  mutate(names = str_replace_all(names, name, ""),
         names = str_remove_all(names, name))
```

---

```r
  name  names       
  <chr> <chr>       
1 Tom   RyanTim     
2 Joe   RobMike     
3 Nick  SteveKevin  
4 Bill  EvanPacJimmy
```

Comment: With `stringr` there's also: `mutate(names = str_remove_all(names, name))`

Comment: like it, although rowwise() seems just fine as well

Answer (score 2):

Or `group_by`:

```r
library(dplyr)

zed |>
  group_by(name, names) |>
  mutate(names = gsub(name, "", names)) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  name  names       
  <chr> <chr>       
1 Tom   RyanTim     
2 Joe   RobMike     
3 Nick  SteveKevin  
4 Bill  EvanPacJimmy
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to loop through your `zed` data frame with `sapply`, and use `gsub` within that.

```
library(dplyr)

zed %>%
  mutate(names = sapply(1:nrow(.), \(x) gsub(.[x, 1], "", .[x, 2])))

  name        names
1  Tom      RyanTim
2  Joe      RobMike
3 Nick   SteveKevin
4 Bill EvanPacJimmy
```